# JVM sawtooth idle process

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm currently doing a research invovling a bit of the JVM and how it's memory usage works. What I don't understand is, what does the JVM fill it's memory with when idle, just to release it all when the heap is almost reached? Why isn't there just one flat line of used memory? btw, this java application is hosted on glassfish, but I have the same graphs when I just have an easy 'hello world' swing application. So GlassFish doesn't have to do anything with it.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958219/jvm-sawtooth-pattern-when-idle-what-does-the-jvm-do-in-the-meantime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958219/jvm-sawtooth-pattern-when-idle-what-does-the-jvm-do-in-the-meantime)

Comment: Note that the JVM you're monitoring is running Glassfish. Servers (particularly JEE servers) are hardly ever *really* idle, they'll almost always do some kind of background bookkeeping, checking caches, low-priority stuff. It's fine to check what that background stuff is, but if you really want to check **JVM** behaviour, I'd rather check a JVM running a long-running `Thread.sleep()` in its single (non-daemon) thread.

Comment: Thanks. I realised that it was running on GlassFish indeed, so i edited the post. I'll try the sleep() method and see what happens :)

Comment: Hey I'm sorry Joachim, what should I have done? I didn't got any replies anymore in that topic as nobody saw it. And it was still unanswered.

Comment: @Rens: [check this question for help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions). Offering a bounty or adding some of your own findings to the question might be a good start. Also, [this blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/).

Comment: Ok Thanks Joachim. Sorry again, wasn't my intention to do it wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what does the JVM fill it's memory with when idle, just to release it all when the heap is almost reached?

If your application is genuinely idle, the most likely case is VisualVM. Try reducing the sample rate and see if the rate memory is consumed also drops.

> Why isn't there just one flat line of used memory?

JMX is written in Java so when it collects stats and serialises the data it generates quite a bit of garbage. You can turn on memory profiling to confirm that all the memory consmption is JMX & VisualVM related.  If you use a commercial profiler which uses a native agent to monitor the JVM you don't see this behaviour. e.g. YourKit doesn't do this.

Comment: Yes this is it! As it turns out, VisualVM indeed shows less memory usages when i change the interval to every 15 seconds instead of every 1 second! Thank you very much! You made me very happy!